# This echo inside an if/else block is not working at the end of a script

Tags: php, echo

I've looked at similar questions posted here as well as did a basic Google search but the best I could find is about why W3Schools is a horrible place to learn from which didn't help much with my problem. I don't necessarily want a solution, I'd prefer an explanation as to why this isn't working as I have had a similar problem in the past but worked around since this is me simply debugging and testing other sections of code.

To begin with, I've got a pesky echo inside an if statement that isn't printing, the funny thing is that neither the if, nor the else block appear to be executed.

My `index.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>A Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
            session_start();

            include "scripts/Employee.php";

            error_reporting(E_ALL);

            $user = new Employee('bbuck', 'password');

            echo "<p>I have some stuff that works here.</p>";

            if (!($user->error() === false)) {
                echo "<p>Authenticated!</p>";
            }
            else {
                echo $user->error();
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `Employee` constructor:

```
public function __construct($username, $password) {
    $db = Database::getInstance();

    $result = $db->authenticate($username, $password);
    if ($result !== false) {
        $this->id = $result['id'];
        $this->fname = $result['fname'];
        $this->lname = $result['lname'];
        $this->lastAction = $result['last_action'];
        $this->error = false;
    }
    else
        $this->error = "Failed to authenticate the user, wrong username/password combination.";
}
```

I don't think it's really important, but just as a reference the `Employee::error()` function is simply `return $this->error;`.

And finally, the `Database::authenticate()` function:

```
public function authenticate($username, $password) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `employee` WHERE `username` = '" 
        . $this->conn->escape_string($username) 
        . "' AND `password` = PASSWORD('"
        . $this->conn->escape_string($password) . "')";

    $result = $this->conn->query($query);

    if (!$result)
        return false;

    $rowCount = $result->num_rows;

    if ($rowCount == 1) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $update = "UPDATE `employee` SET `session_id` = UUID(), `session_expires` = (NOW() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) WHERE `id` = {$row['id']}";
        $select = "SELECT `session_id`, `session_expires` FROM `employee` WHERE `id` = {$row['id']}";

        $updateResult = $this->conn->query($update);

        if (!$updateResult)
            die("Failed to update the employee!");

        $updateResult = $this->conn->query($select);

        if (!$updateResult)
            die("Failed to pull Session data for employee!");

        $updateRow = $updateResult->fetch_assoc();
        $_SESSION[SESSION_ID] = $updateRow['session_id'];
        $_SESSION[SESSION_EXPIRES] = new DateTime($updateRow['session_expires']);

        return $row;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, the echo statements within the `if/else` block of `index.php` are not printing anything, I've used `var_dump` on `$user` and `$user->error() === false` and both gave me the results that I expected to receive from them. I've also placed an `echo` before the if statement and it worked, as well as one after the statement, it also worked. I'm confused as to why they are being overlooked.

This is for debugging, I'm trying to test code, but as I said, I'm curious why this is being skipped because I've encountered this before.

Comment: Have you checked your error log to make sure there's no PHP errors?  Does the stuff after the PHP block get printed out?  (The </body> for example)

Comment: Could it be that it's going in the `else`, and `$user->error()` is returning an empty string or null value, hence no echo?

Comment: Also just noticed that you have session_start after printing html.  session_start requires sending a cookie to the client, which requires sending a HTTP header.  Once data has been passed through other than headers (such as your HTML before the session start call), headers can no longer be sent.  Your session is likely not starting.  Or are you using output buffering? (If you are, it's still better practice to put session_start before output)

Comment: @Corbin Thanks for that bit of info, I didn't know that. I thought it could be called anywhere - I never actually read the Manual for it but I will now.

Comment: @babonk Yes, that was the problem I wasn't paying attention to the conditions, I was expecting the problem to be elsewhere. It's always the simple stuff that trips me up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the full extent of your problem, but your conditions aren't correct.

```
if (!($user->error() === false)) {
    echo "<p>Authenticated!</p>";
}
else {
    echo $user->error();
}
```

The `echo $user->error();` inside the `else` statement will only ever execute if `$user->error() === false`. In this case you will be executing `echo false;`, which will give you no echoed output.

---

To resolve this problem, use this instead (assuming `$user->error();` returns `false` if no errors exist):

```
if ($user->error() === false) {
    echo "<p>Authenticated!</p>";
}
else {
    echo $user->error();
}
```

Comment: Wow. Go figure, it was that simple. I didn't even think about checking the conditions - I was looking for something more complex, it's always something simple. Thanks. (I can't accept as the right answer yet, 2 more minutes :P)

Comment: The funniest thing about it is when I did a `var_dump` to test the condition and make sure it was evaluating properly I did `var_dump($user->error === false)` without the `!` /sigh

Comment: A perfect example of why it's so important to write *simple* code if at all possible. It's very easy to gloss over a `!` symbol at the beginning of an if statement, while `!==` would have been immediately obvious.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Noted. I never thought of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@adlawson is right. You can look in php.ini and see if `display_errors` is set to `On`. If not, set it to `ON`, then execute your script to see if you get an error. Sometimes, if $class->method() returns an error, you might not see it because of `display_errors=Off`.

Comment: No PHP Errors are being generated and I'm using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to set error reporting for the duration of the script which is, at present, the only place I cared to test for it.